# It's possible to create an offline app using flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile-application, flutter-layout, flutter-plugin, flutter-channel

I want to develop offline book reading app using flutter. There is any way in flutter so that user can access book offline.

Comment: Yes it can be done , you can pack the data needed by your app and release. you can read about Assets https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Comment: I want to hide the book user not able to copy a book from my app. There is any way I want to store the whole book contains in encrypted mode, so the user can only read the book.

Comment: Flutter provides the interface to access your stored files, as you are writing your code using dart you can write your own encryption method , and access your files using that method.

Comment: Okay I will try thanks sreeramu

Answer (score 2):

you can put data in form of json and load data when you requires it
you can read more about it here

https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/

Answer (score 0):

You can download the images/pdf files of your book in the device storage (External Storage) by asking user like

"Hey! Do you want this to be available offline? Cool, click the button and grant the storage permission in order to proceed".

After this, you can download the files from the server in device external storage and use it. Simple!